# Computer only POST's with 1 mem stick in socket dimm_B1

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, bios

I've been troubleshooting this for months now without resolve. If anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate it. I'm completely lost at what to do next.

**Problem**

I moved into a new place with high humidity and as a result the PSU (old) started spewing rust "juice" from the fan into the case without me realizing it until it was too late. As a result, water damage occurred on the motherboard and computer would not turn on. I replaced the PSU and motherboard. After putting everything back together I could only get it to POST with 1 memory stick in the dimm_B1 socket. I can't get past this point after troubleshooting.

Whenever I try new memory sticks all the fans turn on, but no video output. If I stick the memory back into dimm_b1 it posts and boots just fine.

No problems working on the computer for several months using 1 stick of memory, but with the work I do I need all four sticks.a

**PC Specs**

CPU: Intel Core i3-4130 Haswell 3.4GHz LGA 1150 54W Dua

RAM: 4 x Crucial Ballistix Sport 1600 mhz 8gb

Graphics: Onboard MB

PSU: 600w

Old MB: ASUS B85M-G LGA 1150 Intel B85 HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB

- https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/B85MG/

NEW MB:  ASUS B85M-G R2.0 LGA 1150 Intel B85 HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 Micro ATX Intel

- https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/B85MG_R20/

**What I've Tried**

Every possible permutation of RAM and dimm slots both individually and combined.

- Only posts with RAM in dimm_b1
- With same RAM that works I tried in other slots and no POST

Replaced new MB (Not old one that had water damage) with exact same motherboard.

- Exact same problem

Checked pins on CPU

- All pins look good; plus, with new motherboard, still same problems

Swapped out new PSU with another PSU I had

- No difference

Updated BIOS

- Bios current and up to date

Checked all connections

- Same problems with POST

Reset CMOS jumper and removed battery

- Same problems with POST

Answer (score 1):

Your RAM is the right voltage for the new mobo, so that common mismatch is out. Are you 100% certain that your new PSU is at the right voltage and current?

Rule out the memory controller in your CPU either by trying same CPU in a known-working setup, or new/known-working CPU in yours.

CPUs are robust, yes, but heat is the enemy and I don't trust the rust juice PSU incident. A really badly placed static discharge is another possibility.

If that doesn't work, I have yet to locate a report of someone getting all four slots working through BIOS (EFI) update alone. However there are enough people who got two dimms working that it may be worth a go. On the other hand, there may be an issue in the newest BIOS, calling for a downgrade. I wouldn't downgrade unless Asus told me to.

If the problem doesn't follow the CPU when swapped, my next stop would be Asus' support. I suspect they'll be stumped too, at least at first, but at that point the symptoms are pointing back towards hardware/software issue in their product.

This doesn't necessarily mean it's broken; possibly just an incompatibility. In narrowing it down they may ask you to try a different brand of RAM. Of course, they will also be suspicious that you may be failing to seat the RAM properly-- having the shop that tests the CPU re-seat the RAM too may alleviate that fear.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yes, the PSU is right voltage and current. I've have tried replacing the current PSU with a new one that I had in a similar setup before and same symptoms. I don't have the ability to test a new CPU, so I may have to take it to a repair shop to try it; however, the only thing that changed from my previous setup was the MB. CPU works fine with one dimm slot. The BIOS update is the newest update from ASUS, so not possible to test this. Any other thoughts?  This rules out everything except for CPU, but CPU's are pretty robust. Thoughts?

Comment: @Amstell Edited accordingly. Dunno why it's not going into dual channel mode, but with any luck you'll be able to track it down